# Assembly mips instruction lbu

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm trying to write a compare string function but I've a problem when I load a character from a address to a register. The error is:

> line 516: Runtime exception at 0x00400600: address out of range 0x6972614d

The error is on the instruction `lbu $t4,($t5)`.
`$t5` contains an address passed with the instruction `la $t5,name0`.

```
search_name:

lbu $t4,($t5)
lbu $t2,0($t6)

beq $t2,10,search_surname   
bne $t2,$t4,loop_search 

addi $t6,$t6,1
addi $t5,$t5,1

j search_name
```

Comment: I guess you should post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: While I'm adimttedly not terribly experienced with MIPS, I don't think the error is in this part of the code. It seems more likely that you're either passing in the wrong address, or have illegal data in there causing it to read out of bounds. (The latter seems less likely given the non-aligned address.)

Comment: Also, if you don't mind me asking, are you absolutely sure that `0x00400600` is that `lbu` instruction? The address just seems to well-aligned to be just any random instruction. Could be both an honest coincidence or because of program organization, of course, but it seems worth verifying.

Comment: I'm sure 'cause the line 516 is the instruction lbu and the program ends on  this line.

Answer (score 0):

That smells like an error with indirection.

`0x6972614d` is ASCII `iraM`, so this looks like you are dereferencing part of your string contents.